# Has a country gone to war to seek payment of a debt since 1900?

Tags: 20th-century, war, economy

Has a country gone to war to seek payment of a debt since 1900? Expansionist policies don't count although use of debt as a justification would be interesting.

Comment: It's probably cheaper to simply write off the debt.

Answer (score 6):

Does the French Occupation of the Ruhr (1923-1925) count, or is that not war-ry enough?

Comment: Please expand your answer to explain what happened along with relevant links.

Comment: Sounds like an acceptable (though shortish) answer to me. The OP can google it to get more information...

Comment: sounds like an interesting example - honestly, I was thinking more 'war' than 'occupation'. 1920's German hyperinflation was obviously the most costly event `writ large` of all time.